# How to properly or securely output data but still be able to display breaks and special characters inputed

Tags: php, security, xss

The function below is the one I use to output data

```
function escape($string){
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

It works if just need to get strings saved to my database and be echoed

How can I allow certain tags like bold and breaks and still be secured from xss attacks

Here is a sample string I need to work

```
$string = '<b onclick="javascript:alert(1);">Hello<br>World<script>alert(2);</script></b>';
```

Output should just be

**Hello
World**

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my question by combining answers I found on this website.

Here's the code

```
$string = '<b onclick="javascript:alert(1);">Hello<br>World<script>alert(2);</script></b>';
// remove script tag along with everything in it
$string = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $string); 
// remove all tags except the ones you want to work
$string = strip_tags($string, '<br><b>');
// remove all attributes of the html tags
$string = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $string);
echo $string;
```

For now, it works against the sample string provided.
If you guys know any problem that might occur by using this code please feel free to comment and advice on better way output data securely but still keep certain tags. Thanks!